# Cannot launch AVD in emulator. sh: grep: command not found

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

In Android Studio, launch AVD Manager, I choose one of my virtual device and click Play button to start it.

Then I get this error message 
`"Cannot launch AVD in emulator. 
sh: file: command not found 
sh: grep: command not found
 ... "`

It's fine all the while and I think I mess up with the PATH variable by running the following command.

```
echo 'export PATH=/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH=/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After executing these, I couldn't find simple command like `ls` in Terminal too. 
Then I fixed it by running

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

After that, `ls`, `grep` etc are working fine again. 
I check it in the Terminal windows, it is showing the same error before, running the above command fixed it.

However, when I try to launch AVD, it still failed with the error message above. 
Try to restart, invalidate cahce, nothing help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting your path wrong. In fact you are just replacing it. What you need to do is to **add** to path. Like this:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Be sure to view ~/.bash_profile in editor and remove previous PATH entries.

Note the added $PATH. This way it takes the previous path and appends the new one.

```
PATH=$PATH:your_path_here
```