# sh: grep: command not found

Tags: docker, command

I'm executing a command `docker ps -a | grep <imagename>` from another container.

It shows

```
sh: grep: command not found
sh: docker: command not found
```

Can anyone support me on it?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on https://superuser.com.

Comment: @reporter, [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) questions are certainly on-topic here.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to run Docker inside of Docker?

Comment: @Chris The tooltip says "Questions about how Docker interacts with programming or programming with Docker containers is on-topic. General support questions for Docker the application may be off topic and better asked on https://superuser.com.". The questioner want to access within a container to another container with a shell command. In my eyes it is an off-topic question. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I believe this question is on topic but lacks enough detail to be answered. Please update the question with what image you are running, and how. Include enough detail that someone else could reproduce your error without access to your environment.

Comment: I have an application (Application1) which executes 'docker ps -a | grep <imagename>'.  With Application1, I create an image say 'Image1'. On running 'Image1', it shows                                                                                                          sh: grep: command not found                                                                sh: docker: command not found                                                                                                            Need support on it.

Comment: I have an application (Application1) which executes 'docker ps -a | grep <imagename>'.  With Application1, I create an image say 'Image1'. On running 'Image1', it shows                                                                                                          sh: grep: command not found                                                                sh: docker: command not found                                                                                                            Need support on it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create `image1`, depending on its base image:

- it might not have docker installed in it (see "[How to install docker in docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44451859/6309)")
- it might not have `grep` installed (depending on your base image, or your [`$PATH` defined in that image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723546/6309) )

So start by checking those two factors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for an image name, you can try:

```
docker ps --filter ancestor=image_name
```

If you are searching for a container name, you can try:

```
docker ps --filter "name=container_name"
```

But the fellas are right, if you don't have docker installed on that container, you won't be able to execute the **docker ps** command.